# ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Resulta que recién estoy empezando en node y tengo un error que no puedo lograr resolver, ya busque en google varias veces, por todos lados en realidad y no puedo dar con la solución, estos son mis archivos y el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.js

```js
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

//archivos rutas
var project_routes = require('./routes/usuarios');

//midlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS

//rutas

app.use('/', project_routes);

//exportar

module.exports = app;
```

Y el archivo index.js:

```js
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = 3700;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Hotel')
                .then(() =>{
                  console.log("Funciona la bdd");
                  //creacion del sv
                  app.listen(port, () => {
                    console.log("Servidor corriendo correctamente");

                  });

                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor incluir tu fichero de routes/usuarios?